# Starting publishing services with ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, publishing, services

I have just installed ArcGIS for Server 10.2 on my server and the publishing services will not start.

Has anyone had issues with this before?

The error message that I receive after the service fails to start is:

> **Service failed to start  System.PublishingTools.GPServer: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested
> exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset**

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Windows registry path at`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath`the value should look something like `C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk`

You must have this string value in your registry. So if it does not exist then you must create a new one with the same characteristic key string.

Comment: Rico, I solved my issue by disconnecting all of the SDE connections/users and then restarting the service. For some strange-ESRI reason that was all it took.

Comment: Thanks Lieg.  I also faced this issue, once i edited the registry, it worked fine.